# Ansible OpenShift shell command fails, but works outside of Ansible

Tags: ansible, openshift-3

I have an Ansible playbook that includes an OpenShift CLI login:

```
- name: "OpenShift CLI login"
  shell: oc login -u kubeadmin -p $(cat /root/auth/kubeadmin-password) https://{{ groups['boot'][0] }}:6443
```

It fails with (hostname has been replaced below):

```
fatal: [<host>]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "oc login -u kubeadmin -p $(cat /root/auth/kubeadmin-password) https://<host>:6443", "delta": "0:00:00.228068", "end": "2020-02-19 09:47:32.651617", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-02-19 09:47:32.423549", "stderr": "error: The server is using a certificate that does not match its hostname: x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, openshift, openshift.default, openshift.default.svc, openshift.default.svc.cluster.local, 172.30.0.1, not <host>", "stderr_lines": ["error: The server is using a certificate that does not match its hostname: x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, openshift, openshift.default, openshift.default.svc, openshift.default.svc.cluster.local, 172.30.0.1, not <host>"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

But if I run the command directly, it works:

```
oc login -u kubeadmin -p $(cat /root/auth/kubeadmin-password) https://<host>:6443
Login successful.
You have access to 55 projects, the list has been suppressed. You can list all projects with 'oc projects'
Using project "openshift-image-registry".
```

Any thoughts on why it fails under Ansible?  Ansible version is 2.4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The shell module runs a /bin/sh shell.

You are probably running /bin/bash and you have config in .bashrc that is not being activated.

Try something like this:

```
- name: "OpenShift CLI login"  
  shell: /bin/bash oc login -u kubeadmin -p $(cat /root/auth/kubeadmin-password) https://{{ groups['boot'][0] }}:6443
```

Comment: Odd:

```
fatal: [<host>]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/bash oc login -u kubeadmin -p $(cat /root/auth/kubeadmin-password) https://<host>:6443", "delta": "0:00:00.007296", "end": "2020-02-19 11:48:04.506336", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 126, "start": "2020-02-19 11:48:04.499040", "stderr": "oc: oc: cannot execute binary file", "stderr_lines": ["oc: oc: cannot execute binary file"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
 to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/deploy.retry
```

Comment: Starting to think there is something weird about the oc command, itself.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with the certificate installed in OCP.  I can bypass the problem with the flag `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` on the `oc login` command.  Talking to our OCP admins...